# Saiku e CDE não estão trazendo dados específicos

Tags: pentaho

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou com o seguinte problema:

No meu Saiku e CDE não estão trazendo dados do dia '19/02/2017'. No arquivo fonte(excel), banco e OLTP, mostram normalmente (são 192 registros). Já olhei a minha dim_data, cubo e nada. Testei no PowerBI e trouxe normalmente os dados...Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Depende, você está trabalhando com filtros?

Comment: Provavelmente, há algum filtro ou algum problema com o tipo de dado de data que a ferramenta está tendo dificuldade de trabalhar.